# Create automatic latest version link

Tags: plugins, themes

I don't know if it's the right place for this question but this just popped into my head...

Is there a way to create a generic link that redirects `mydomain.com/mytheme/latest` to `mydomain.com/themes/packages/mytheme1.1.zip` or something like.

And the generic link is automatically updated when I have a newer version of the theme. So whenever I want to get the latest version I'd use that generic link. That's crazy!

Maybe this can be done for plugins/themes from Wordpress.org. But this one is made by me.

Or should I do this manually?

Thanks

Comment: You could declare the version as a constant and use that constant as both the version number and the variable for the version number in a given url string.

Comment: This isn't really related to WordPress itself. This would be related to whatever system you're deploying packages to.